# Whole class exception

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I've got some problems trying to make the only common exception for my whole class. Could somebody tell me how make that? Before that I tried to make little try-throw-catch blocks like that:

```
try {
    Integer a = 10;
    if(a == 10) 
        throw(/*what to write here?*/)
}

//some code later... or here must be NO code because catch goes right after the try(if I'm not mistaken)?

catch(/*what to write here?*/){
    System.err.println("smth gone wrong");   
}
```

So the question is how to create one big exception for whole class and how to make correctly example above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define an Exception that you want to throw, specify that a method in your class throws it, and then catch that Exception when you try that method. Exception throws are not defined at a class-level, though - they are defined per-method.

[See Oracle's Documentation On Throwing Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html) for more details.